# codeigniter template engine including language parser

Tags: php, codeigniter, template-engine

I don’t see any mechanism to refer to a language_key within a view that will be rewritten by the Template Parser. Right now, my view contains strings like:

```
{register}
{userid}
{password}
```

I want these replaced by the matching strings from the Language definition, as if I had done this in the view:

```
   <?=$this->lang->line('register')?>
   <?=$this->lang->line('userid')?>
   <?=$this->lang->line('password')?>
```

However, I don’t see any mechanism to support this automatically. So, I’m doing this in the controller:

```
$data = array(
'userid' => $this->lang->line('userid'),
'password' => $this->lang->line('password'),
'register' => $this->lang->line('register')
);
$this->parser->parse('register', $data);
```

This seems rather silly to me. I think the Template Parser class should automatically support expansion of any defined language_keys. Perhaps by using a second set of delimiters:

```
[register]
[userid]
[password]
```

Or maybe by using a certain indicator like an underscore:

```
{_register}
{_userid}
{_password}
```

Or perhaps the GetText style:

```
_(register)
_(userid)
_(password)
```

Can somebody please tell me if the functionality I’m looking for is actually available and I just missed it? Otherwise, do my suggestions seem reasonable, or is there perhaps an even better alternative idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately CI's built in template parser class doesn't have this functionality. You can look around in the [sparks directory](http://getsparks.org/), there's multiple sparks that integrates numerous template engines like smarty or twig that could be tweaked to create something like this.

Also, you can try extending the `CI_Parser` class to do this for you like this:

```
<?php

class MY_Parser extends CI_Parser {

    const LANG_REPLACE_REGEXP = '!\{_\s*(?<key>[^\}]+)\}!';
    public $CI = null;

    public function parse($template, $data, $return = FALSE) {
        $this->CI = get_instance();
        $template = $this->CI->load->view($template, $data, TRUE);
        $template = $this->replace_lang_keys($template);

        return $this->_parse($template, $data, $return);
    }

    protected function replace_lang_keys($template) {
        return preg_replace_callback(self::LANG_REPLACE_REGEXP, array($this, 'replace_lang_key'), $template);
    }

    protected function replace_lang_key($key) {
        return $this->CI->lang->line($key[1]);
    }
}
```

This will replace `{_ password}` like parts with what `$this->lang->line('password')` would. The pattern can be tweaked for your favourite version.

Putting this under `application/libraries/MY_Parser.php` and CI should pick it up, no controller code will have to be changed, as described in the [*Extending Native Libraries*](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) part.

Comment: Perfect answer! Using this in all my projects now

Comment: How could I modify the regular expression to ignore handlebars templates? `{{#each element}}<p>{{name}}</p>{{/each}}`

Comment: @thiagobraga, As long as you don't have a `{_` in your handlebar block you should be fine with the pattern as is.

Comment: @complex857 Sorry, forgot to say, I've been using your class for some time perfectly, with the language translation coming from database. But I modified the language keys in PHP files to `{{i18n_text}}`. Now I'm using Handlebars templates in `<script>` tags in my view files, and modified recently the language keys to `{i18n_text}` to not conflict with Handlebars, but the regular expression doesn't work properly for the two cases. I think your idea is good, maybe I change the keys to `{_i18n_text}` to avoid this errors. Thanks!

Comment: I think if you add some negative lookahead/lookbehind to the mix you can make this work, so something like: `#(?!\})\{i18n_(?<key>[^\}]+)\}(?!\})#` should only match `{i18n_text}` if there are no extra pair of `{` `}` around it ([more info here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).